# Yacht Seller + Lord Mayor >> should anchors been counted

Tags: harbour

Playing Harbour with:

- custom characters, especially Lord Mayor: *You may use Top Hats as they were both Top Hats & Anchors*
- High Tides expansion, especially Yacht Seller: *worth 3 Victory Points per anchor you have*

At the end of the game, would you count Top Hats + Anchors for the Victory Points of the Yacht Seller?

Comment: Looks like a similar discussion happing on BGG https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2699809/lord-mayor-use-game-end-scoring

Comment: @StartPlayer Yeah, I started that thread in response to this question, since BGG is much more likely to elicit novel rulings from official sources.

Answer (score 3):

On [this thread in BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2699809/lord-mayor-use-game-end-scoring), Seth Jaffee of TMG says that Yacht Seller won't count Top Hats even with Lord Mayor.

> It's been a while and I've never personally played High Tide, but if the text you quoted is accurate, then you don't "have" anchors, it's just that your Top Hats act like anchors (for their effect)

> If that's the wording, the ruling would be "no, you don't score 3vp per Top Hat, you score 3vp per Anchor"

(I also have sent an email to support at TMG for additional confirmation, but haven't heard back yet).